# How to run behaviors on NAO robot without PC?

Tags: nao-robot

I've just started working with NAO on Choreographe and I would like to know if there is a possible way to run behaviors without PC. Can I upload some behaviors to NAO and start running without pressing the run button on Choreographe?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can !
In Choreographe, find the "robot application" widget and then you can upload your program and define it as a "start at boot" program.

Here's a video showing that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9RFkpI4vjo